# What does @! Before a path name do in a ksh script

Tags: unix, ksh

Basically I want to know what this line of scripting code does

```
function make_expand_query_string_shell {
    cat <<DONE | tr '@' '#'
    @!/usr/bin/ksh
    DONE
```

Comment: Are you sure that's not `#!` ?

Comment: Yea I'm looking at this script that I didn't write and it's @! before the path name. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Is it on the first line?

Comment: I edited the question. It is apart of the function above

Comment: Ah, so it's part of a "here document". `man ksh` and search for `<<`

Comment: Note that the "DONE" word at the bottom of that function **must not** have any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: It doesn't in the script just indented it to show it was apart of the function.

Comment: The << is a shift to the left. What I don't understand is the @! before the path

Comment: The << is not a shift to the left. It's a "here document."

Comment: Please show it in your question the way it appears in the script. The added indentation is incorrect. (I don't know why it's not just `echo '#!/usr/bin/ksh'`. Perhaps the author thought a `#` marks a comment even in a string literal. It doesn't.)

Comment: That's an odd way of avoiding comment parsing... Why not just `\#!/bin/ksh`? Actually, for that matter, "comments" embedded in here-docs are probably just treated literally, anyway. So it's probably just paranoia...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat <<DONE | tr '@' '#'
@!/usr/bin/ksh
DONE`

This is a Unix "pipeline" tying together a few useful utilities to create some output.

The shell itself is going to read the first line, and break it down approximately as so:

- `cat` — is the name of a program, which will be found on the `PATH`. The `cat` program is used to con`cat`enate files together.
- `<<` — is used to "redirect" the standard input to the program coming before it. Since there is nothing between `cat` and `<<`, the program will be started without any command-line parameters (e.g. filenames), and like many shell utilities, will expect its input from the "standard input" stream.
- `DONE` is a symbol that is, essentially, a parameter to `<<`.
- `|` instructs the shell to "pipe" the standard output from the program to its left (`cat`) to the program to its right (`tr`).
- `tr` is the name of another program. Its purpose is to `tr`anslate or `tr`anspose characters.
- `'@' '#'` are command-line parameters to `tr`.

The `<<` feature is called a "here-document." Every Unix program starts its life with three standard I/O streams (except under unusual circumstances) — its standard input, output, and error output. Normally, all three are connected to your terminal.

In this case, however, `<<` will essentially link the standard input to the sequence of lines in the script file, itself, until it reads a line that matches the ending symbol given — in this case, `DONE`. It's called a "here-document" because the document being fed to the input is given "here" — immediately in the script file, itself.

As @KeithThompson recommended, you could have found this in the `ksh` manual, by searching for "<<":

```
<<[-]word

The shell input is read up to a line that is the same as
word after any quoting has been removed, or to an end-of-
file. No parameter substitution, command substitution,
arithmetic substitution or file name generation is per-
formed on word. The resulting document, called a here-
document, becomes the standard input. If any character
of word is quoted, then no interpretation is placed upon
the characters of the document; otherwise, parameter
expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic substitu-
tion occur, \new-line is ignored, and \ must be used to
quote the characters \, $, �. If - is appended to <<,
then all leading tabs are stripped from word and from the
document. If # is appended to <<, then leading spaces
and tabs will be stripped off the first line of the docu-
ment and up to an equivalent indentation will be stripped
from the remaining lines and from word. A tab stop is
assumed to occur at every 8 columns for the purposes of
determining the indentation.
```

Likewise, the `|` is taking the output from `cat` and passing it directly to the input of `tr`.

So, what do these two programs do? Let's check their manuals.

```
NAME
     cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output
SYNOPSIS
     cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
DESCRIPTION
     Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.
```

OK … so, this will concatenate its standard input to its standard output. What about `tr`?

```
NAME
    tr - translate or delete characters
SYNOPSIS
    tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]
DESCRIPTION
    Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writ-
    ing to standard output.
```

…

```
    SETs are specified as strings of characters. Most represent them-
    selves.
```

So `tr` well translate a character in SET1 to the character in the same position in SET2. Looks like we have two sets with only one member each, so that's easy to see what will happen.

Since `cat` does not do anything to its input except copy it to its output, it's being used to effectively copy the here-document as the input to `tr`. In turn, `tr` is transposing every `@` on its input into a `#`.

This creates, as its output, a typical Unix "shebang" line, of `#!/usr/bin/ksh`.

The entire sequence is a much more ornate version of

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/ksh'
```

Comment: `s/ornate/convoluted/`

Comment: I vaguely hope there's some horrible tool out there that was accidentally mangling the shebang line in some disturbing way, but the only thing that I could come up with was maybe `cpp` and that seems extraordinarily unlikely … "convoluted" at best, and "intentionally obfuscated" seems more likely, although I can't imagine why